# Why are there so many late answers in the queue?

Tags: discussion, late-answers

Is there a reason for so many late answers popping up in the review queue? I think 2 days ago, there might have been 20. Now there are 2.5k.
What happened?

Comment: It is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-bypass-the-review-queue)

Comment: @kos didn't get the newsletter. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Late Answer" reputation bar was raised from 10 to 50. This is to fight all the comments-as-answers that still appear and escape the current review queue.

More details are available over on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-bypass-the-review-queue).

Comment: Ouch. I will take your word for it, That thread is painful. I guess this happened just recently.